# append URL string after domain name or file name

Tags: php, redirect

i am passing a url as a param to the next page. ?url=http://domain.com i would like to set additional param to a querystring or the url. but only if a specific domain exists in the querystring.
i tried

```
$url = preg_replace('{http://www.domain.com}','http://www.domain.com?foo=bar/',$_GET['url']);
```

but this is not working when there is a file name or other params.
any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you try to go to a url with a query string, it will always redirect to the url with the `/`. This is required to separate the domain from the path and query string. And the query string (key/value after `?`) is always required to be at the end of the string after any path (not counting the hash). The trailing `/` in your example, would just get appended to the value for `foo`.

Comment: "i would like to add..." Why?

Comment: to add an affiliate tracking. so basically to make it simple. how can i simply add a param as the first param in the url if the param does not exist already.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to place some parameter to the beginning of the query string you can use `parse_url` function:

```
$url = "http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

$parsed_url = parse_url($url);
$new_url = $parsed_url['path'] ."?foo=bar" . ((isset($parsed_url['query']))? urlencode("&").$parsed_url['query'] : "");
var_dump($new_url);

// the output: string(45) "http://www.domain.com?foo=bar%26param=value"
```

Comment: i cannot set $url =  becouse the url is dynamic and can be any url. i only want to modify if a specific domain exists and to add affiliate id to it

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want:

```
$url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]"; // the URL you want to inject the parameters into
$params = "new=yes!"; // the new parameters you want to add at the beginning
if (strpos($url, "?") !== false) {
        list($url, $b) = explode("?", $url, 2);
        $params = "$params&$b";
}
$url .= "?".$params;
```

Output: `http://example.com/example.php?new=yes!&a=b&c=no`

Comment: i cannot set $url =  becouse the url is dynamic and can be any url.

Comment: @SammyMiri I changed the code to use the current URL of the website.

Comment: i cannot set $url = becouse the url is dynamic and can be any url. i only want to modify if a specific domain exists and to add affiliate id to i

Comment: @Sammy Either change your question or ask a different question then. This answers already applies it to the current URL but checking the domain is out of scope for the current question,